# RANK records partitioned by a column in series (Vertica SQL)

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to use the Vertica rank analytic function to create a rank column partitioned by a column, but only include records that are in a series.  For example the query below produces the output below the query

```
select when_created, status
from tablea

when_created    Status
1/1/2015    ACTIVE
3/1/2015    ACTIVE
4/1/2015    INACTIVE
4/6/2015    INACTIVE
6/7/2015    ACTIVE
10/9/2015   INACTIVE
```

I could modify my query to include a rank column which would produce the following output

```
select 
when_created, status, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY status order by when_created) as rnk
from tablea

when_created    Status  rnk
1/1/2015    ACTIVE  1
3/1/2015    ACTIVE  2
4/1/2015    INACTIVE    1
4/6/2015    INACTIVE    2
6/7/2015    ACTIVE  3
10/9/2015   INACTIVE    3
```

However my goal is start over the rank when a series is broken so the desired output is:

```
when_created    Status  rnk
1/1/2015    ACTIVE  1
3/1/2015    ACTIVE  2
4/1/2015    INACTIVE    1
4/6/2015    INACTIVE    2
6/7/2015    ACTIVE  1
10/9/2015   INACTIVE    1
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using the RANK function or is there another way to do it in vertica sql?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem, where the tricky part is to identify the groups to use for a `row_number()` calculation.  One solution uses a difference of row numbers to identify the different groups:

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by status, seqnum - seqnum_s order by when_created) as rnk
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by when_created) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by when_created) as seqnum_s
      from tablea a
     ) a;
```

The logic behind this is tricky when you first see it.  I advise you to run the subquery and understand the two `row_number()` calculations -- and to observe that the difference is constant for the groups you are interested in.

Comment: Wow that is really clever!  Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks a ton @GordonLinoff. I came searching for the same logic and got it. Thank you!!!